# Can I use Spring transaction without Spring JDBC / Hibernate with plain java.sql package classes?

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-transactions

How can I use Spring transaction management without Spring-jdbc or any other framework?

I want to inject `DataSource` and execute `PreparedStatements` / `Statements` / `CallableStatements`, not `JdbcTemplate`

Is it possible with spring? if so then How ?

Comment: @FarazDurrani Please explain How. Because while using JdbcTemplate it is working fine but while using connection.createStatement it is running in it's own transaction

Comment: See. I wanted to remove my comment when I fully understood your question. lol Sorry.

Comment: But, I still think it is definitely possible

Comment: When you setup Spring framework and setup hibernate, I think you setup/use EntityManager. Then you can get org.hibernate.Session object by using Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class); Then you can use session.createSQLQuery  method. You can run native sql queies that way. But I don't think you can run preparedStatements

Comment: @FarazDurrani I am not using Hibernate, In fact I am not using any framework. I am using Spring-Jdbc and I want to remove that dependency  also please read the question carefully

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It sounds really strange, and that usually means that you're solving the wrong problem.

Comment: @EngineerDollery I am not doing this for production. I just want to know that if that is possible with Spring Transaction.If so How do i configure it that way

Comment: Well, spring transaction is just a set of classes, so potentially you can use it any way you want, but you'd just end up implementing yourself what spring gives you for 'free'.